# .NET Framework 4 ILASM targeting framework 2

Tags: .net, frameworks, ilasm

Question: I need to create, using `ILASM.EXE`, framework 2.0 assemblies.

So far, I have seen that fw 2 ilasm: creates 2.0 assembies.
FW 4 ilasm, on the other hand: creates 4.0 assemblies.

So far I am cool.

Now I need to know: is there a way (perhaps an argument) that can be used to make fw 4 ilasm to create fw 2 assemblies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET 4 cannot target .NET 3.5 or .NET 2.0, that's why if you want to compile .NET 2.0 or 3.5 assemblies, with visual studio 2010, you need to also have .NET 3.5 installed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197(VS.100).aspx

Comment: My mistake, it only requires that .NET 3.5 is intstalled

Comment: No, you don't need VS 2008 to do so: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/27/multi-targeting-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx

Comment: I was wrong that VS2010 required VS2008 to compile .NET 3.5 or 2.0, however it is true that .NET 4 cannot generate .NET 3.5 or 2.0 assemblies.

Comment: I must say, on the other hand, that ILDASM has no problem in any direction.